# Is there anything that I can do to speed up write to csv time in python?

Tags: python, csv, hadoop, hive

I am trying to create a small application that will help me extract data from Hadoop via hiveserver2 by simply writing it to CSV.  At the moment, it takes about 40 seconds to pull 10,000 records from a hs2 table consisting of 500k rows with 203 columns.  I would like to think that there is a faster, more efficient way of doing this than the way I am doing it now.  Ideally I would like to eventually be able to pull and write 1 million rows per minute...It doesn't necessarily have to be written to CSV.  It probably isn't feasible with my current skill level, but I like to set goals for myself.  I appreciate any help that you all may be able to offer me :).

```
import pyhs2
import time
import csv

csv_out = open('data.csv', 'wb')
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
```

storing user name and password in its own function for now...

```
def generic_user():
    gu = 'xxxxxx'
    return gu

def password():
    pw = 'xxxxx'
    return pw
```

This is just the connection to my hive server using pyhs2

```
with pyhs2.connect(host='xxxxxxxx',
               port=10000,
               authMechanism='PLAIN',
               user=generic_user(),
               password=password(),
               database='xxxxxxx') as conn:

    with conn.cursor() as cur:
```

accounting for lower case letters because they adversely affect the query

```
        q = raw_input('Enter query: ').replace('csc', 'CSC')
        print q

        #timer start
        start_time = time.time()

        #Execute query
        cur.execute(q)
```

Creating empty list to store column names extracted from a dictionary

```
        col = []
```

Iterating through each individual dictionary key and appending to col

```
        for key in cur.getSchema():
            col.append(key['columnName'])
```

For some reason with pyhs2 it parses each letter of the dictionary value so I had to append that into another list titled header.

```
        header = []
        header.append(col)
```

Finally writing each header to its column in the csv

```
        for rows in zip(header):
            mywriter.writerows(rows)
```

Pulling the list of records and writing one at a time

```
        records = cur.fetch()
        for rows in zip(records):
            mywriter.writerows(rows)
```

Just printing time to compare performance

```
pull_time = time.time() - start_time
print pull_time
```

Comment: Working code belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AlexHall Sorry, I didnt know that existed.  Ill move my post there, thanks